# Selecting/Filtering Data from LiteDB in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, litedb

I'm trying to retrieve data from a LiteDB NOSQL database but i'm struggling to get the syntax correct in Visual Basic.

The database is created correct (validated in LiteDBViewer) and I can count the values in the collection, but when I try to generate the query using `collection.Find()`, Intellisense puts in `query:=`, not `Query.Operation`, as per the documentation.

```
Try
    Using db As LiteDB.LiteDatabase = New LiteDB.LiteDatabase("Sig.db")
        Dim brands = db.GetCollection(Of Brand)("Brand")
        Dim brands_count As Integer = brands.Count()

        If brands_count > 0 Then
            'get Brands
             Dim brands_results = brands.Find(query:=("Name")) <-- Problem Row
             Dim brand_name As String

                    For Each result In brands_results
                        brand_name = result.Name.ToString
                        BrandGrid.Rows.Add(New String() {brand_name, True, True})
                    Next

            End If
        End Using

    Catch SQLex As LiteDB.LiteException
        MessageBox.Show(SQLex.Message, SQLex.ErrorCode.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.InnerException.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

I guess I'm struggling with the converting the c# code to VB.net or missing something obvious.

All help or advice appreciated.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this all works if I use `brands.FindAll()`. What I'm struggling with is using the `Find()` operator and the querying/filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking to the developer over Twitter, he suggested using Lambda Expressions.

As a result, the value is as follows:

`Dim brands_results = brands.Find(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(SelectedBrand))`

(`SelectedBrand` being a string variable declared earlier)